# How to you change the value of android:summary on-the-fly using coding?

Tags: android, string, preferences, preferenceactivity, on-the-fly

I have the following in a settings.xml file:

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/chiming_activity_time_category_title">

    <Preference android:title="@string/chiming_start_time_title"
        android:summary="@string/chiming_start_time_summary" android:key="preferences_start_time" />
</PreferenceCategory>
```

And this is from the strings.xml file:

```
<string name="chiming_start_time_summary">Allow chiming to be active STARTING from
```

Can you tell me how you change the value of android:summary on-the-fly using coding?

I need to have it display different values based on what the user selects in the preferences screen.

Thanks.

Truly,
Emad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Took a look at the documentation? [setSummary](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#setSummary%28int%29)
You can find your Preference in the PreferenceActivity with [findPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html#findPreference%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

[Documetation of PreferenceActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html) shows you how setup your activity (which you probably did).

Do something like that on end of `onCreate`:

```
findPreference("keyOfPreferenceWhichChanges").setOnPreferenceChangeListener(
        new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
       if (somethingChanged) {
            findPreference("keyOfPreferenceWithNewSummary").setSummary("here's the change!");
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Knickedi, Thanks for the quick reply. Can you show me some code samples with setSummary and how to get that changes to show up on the preference screen as soon as setSummary is used?